# Python MVC Routing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model-view-controller, python-2.7, webapp2

I have the same question as this; -- it has never been answered.

I want to be able to route my requests in a similar way ASP.net MVC does.

For example the address /Home/Index/query-string/ should map the request to HomeController and call the Index method.

I made an implementation for this and it works, but I want to know a better way to do it. I've 
just started using Google App Engine and Python for the first time and I don't have much experience for developing websites and web applications.

Here's my implementation

The Yaml file:

```
- url: /.*
script: router.app
```

Routing Configuration:

```
def StartUp():
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'System'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Controllers'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Models'))
    app.run()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([webapp2.Route('/', handler=Router, name='Default', defaults={'handler': 'home', 'method': 'index', 'query': ''}, build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<query>', handler=Router, name='DefaultC', defaults={'handler': 'home', 'method': 'index'}, build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<handler>/', handler=Router, name='DefaultCS', defaults={'method': 'index', 'query': ''}, build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<handler>/<query>', handler=Router, name='DefaultCA', defaults={'method': 'index'}, build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<handler>/<method>/', handler=Router, name='DefaultCAS', defaults={'query': ''}, build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<handler>/<method>/<query>', handler=Router, name='DefaultAll', build_only=False, handler_method='map'),
                            webapp2.Route('/<handler>/<method>/<query>/', handler=Router, name='DefaultAllS', build_only=False, handler_method='map')],
                            debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StartUp()
```

The router

```
class Router(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def getControllerName(self, handler):
            handler = handler.lower()
            if(len(handler) == 0):
                    """ Error - redirect to error page """
                    return webapp2.redirect('/Error/')
            if len(handler) == 1:
                    handler = handler[0].capitalize()
            else:
                    handler = handler[0].capitalize() + handler[1:]

            handler = handler + 'Controller'

            return handler

    def getActionName(self, method):
            method = method.lower()
            if(len(method) == 0):
                    """ Error - redirect to error page """
                    return webapp2.redirect('/Error/')
            if len(method) == 1:
                    method = method[0].capitalize()
            else:
                    method = method[0].capitalize() + method[1:]

            requestType = self.request.method.lower()
            requestType = requestType[0].capitalize() + requestType[1:]

            return method

    def loadController(self, controllerName):
            """ Load the controller """
            try:
                    fileName, pathName, description = imp.find_module(controllerName, None)
                    module = imp.load_module(controllerName, fileName, pathName, description)

                    # Add checking if class was found
                    controllerRef = getattr(module, controllerName)
                    return controllerRef

            except ImportError, args:
                    logging.error('Error importing controller. ' + pprint.saferepr(args))
            except Exception, args:
                    logging.error('Exception. ' + pprint.saferepr(args))
            finally:
                    fileName.close()

    def loadAction(self, controller, actionName):
            try:
                    actionRef = getattr(controller, actionName)
            except Exception, args:
                    logging.error('Exception. ' + pprint.saferepr(args))
            return actionRef

    def callController(self, controllerName, actionName, query):
            try:
                    """ Load the controller """
                    controllerRef = self.loadController(controllerName)
                    controller = controllerRef(self, query)
                    actionRef = self.loadAction(controller, actionName)
                    actionRef()
            except Exception, args:
                    logging.error('Exception. ' + pprint.saferepr(args))

    def map(self, handler, method, query):
            query = query.lower()
            """ Create Names for Controller and Action"""
            controllerName = self.getControllerName(handler)
            actionName = self.getActionName(method)

            self.callController(controllerName, actionName, query)
```

Here's my Home controller:

```
class HomeController(MVC.Controller):

    def Index(self):

            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('Views/Home/'), 'home.html')
            self.Request.response.out.write(template.render(path, None))
```

Comment: There is the [Flask method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations)